# 'User' object has no attribute 'guild' AttributeError

Tags: python, discord

This command is supposed to apply the role to the mentioned user. My code:

```
    @commands.command(name="manualverify")
    async def manualverify(self, ctx, membertag:discord.User, ethaddy):
         member = membertag
         var6 = discord.utils.get(member.guild_roles, name = str("SAINT_LESS"))
         await member.add_roles(var6)
```

Here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xcopy bot\cogs\main.py", line 447, in manualverify
    var6 = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name = str("SAINT_LESS"))
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how I could fix this?

Comment: membertag:discord.Member?

Comment: The error message and the code differ: in the error, it says `guild.roles` and in the code you provided it says `guild_roles`. Have you saved your `main.py` file after making the change?

Answer (score 0):

As said in BubbyBob's comment, the following code will work. Members have a guild attribute while Users do not. This can be seen [here in the Discord.py documentation.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#member)

```
@commands.command(name="manualverify")
async def manualverify(self, ctx, membertag:discord.Member, ethaddy):
     member = membertag
     var6 = discord.utils.get(member.guild_roles, name = str("SAINT_LESS"))
     await member.add_roles(var6)
```